# Split into columns using three different separators

Tags: excel, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to convert an Excel field into three columns based on these three delimiters: forward slash, dash, and close parenthesis: **) / -**

[image]

And here is what I need to see:

[image]

I've tried the 'Text to Columns' Data Tool in excel, but it cannot accept three custom separators at once.

---

I want a simple and fast Excel method that can convert the following pattern:
[image]

Comment: Do you need the opening paranthesis for a specific reason or is that a typo?

Comment: @JvdV Thank you for comment. That is the dataset we have. So I have to convert this dataset to a one suitable for analysis.

Comment: So you don't want the opening psranthesis either?

Comment: @JvdV Yes, please see the edited post.

Comment: So would you need to split that pattern into different cells or just one?

Comment: @JvdV If one needs only one field, how the formula is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has Excel O365, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MID(CONCAT(IFERROR(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)*1,"")),{1,4,7},{3,3,4}))
```

Now you can throw any pattern at the formula as long as you provide the usual 10 digits.

If always these three same patterns, you could also use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MID(RIGHT(A1,12),{1,5,9},{3,3,4}))
```

This last, simpler solution can also be used in Excel prior to O365 if one used `INDEX()`:

```
=INDEX(MID(RIGHT($A1,12),{1,4,7},{3,3,4}),COLUMN(A1))
```

Drag this formula right, and down.

---

If your goal was to ***ultimately*** have this pattern in a single cell then things became much easier in an instant, and you can use:

```
=REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,12),4,1,"-")
```

[image]

---

If you need to do this in GS then try:

```
=SPLIT(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,12),4,1,"-"),"-")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have a question, is it possible to do the same thing in Google spreadsheets?

Comment: And I have a request. I'm an excel newbie, I would be grateful if you could interpret your excel formula step by step.

Comment: @sci9, Your question is tagged Excel. But yes it's possible in GS too. Since it's a different application there are some other possibilities, however that is beyond the scope of your current question. Can you first clarify if you need it in seperate columns ***or*** in a single cell?

Comment: Actually what I finally need is to separate them into three columns.

Comment: Also the last method you provided is really simple and pretty does what I need. '=REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,12),4,1,"-")' After that we can use simply Text2Col Data tool. I think this approach also works with GS.

Comment: @sci9, GS got a function called `SPLIT()`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `FILTERXML`/`SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<a><b>'" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"/","</b><b>'"),")","</b><b>'"),"-","</b><b>'") & " </b></a>","//b[" & COLUMN(A:A) & "]"),"'","")
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to add one more `Substitute` to replace the opening parenthesis, as required by OP, i.e.: `= SUBSTITUTE( FILTERXML( "<a><b>'" & SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( $D4, "(", "" ), "/", "</b><b>'" ), ")", "</b><b>'" ), "-", "</b><b>'" ) & " </b></a>", "//b[" & COLUMN(A:A) & "]" ), "'", "" )`

Comment: @basic Thank you for your answer. Could you kindly please interpret your formula for a newbie?

Comment: Upvoted since I think `FILTERXML()` is awesome =), but I think a much shorter version could be: `=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(RIGHT($A2,12),4,1,"-"),"-","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),COLUMN(A2))`. Drag right and down. @EEM

Comment: @JvdV thanks for the heads up, I agree FILTERXML is great. I like your shorter version. Did you tested for this two values: `(031)5440-6622` & `021-8886-3877` I could not get the expected results.

Comment: @EEM, you won't get the correct results as the above was meant to deal with the three different possible pattern OP provided =)

Comment: @JvdV these patterns are in the question, have a look at the first image.

Comment: True OP is definately not clear about his needs =) @EEM. Since his latest update I worked around these three provided patterns.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to first fix the data and then run `TextToColumns`.  Select the cells you wish to process and run this short VBA macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FixPhoneData()
    Dim cell As Range, v As String
    
    For Each cell In Selection
        With cell
            v = .Value
            v = Replace(v, ")", "-")
            v = Replace(v, "/", "-")
            .Value = v
        End With
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]